# CSS: Make sure footer at the bottom of the page and inside the shadow

Tags: html, css

I have written webpages like below structure and all the contents are inside `<div id="wrapper">`.

**Problem 1:** If the webpage is only few lines (or shorter than the vertical resolution) How can I make sure the left/right-shadow can be appear from top to bottom?

**Problem 2:** If the webpage is only few lines, how can I place the footer at the bottom of the page and inside the left/right-shadow?

It is appreciated if only CSS be changed. THX~

From this[image] to this[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#mainWrapper {
    width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
}
#wrapper {
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    background:#fff;
}
#pageFooter {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background:#999;
}
</style>
</head>    
<body>
<div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        ContentContentContent
        <div id="pageFooter">
            FooterFooterFooter
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#pageFooter {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}

/* IE 6 */
* html #pageFooter {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

From Chris Coyer's [CSSTricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/)

Comment: THX deadlock. How can I make sure the left/right-shadow can be appear from top to bottom?

Comment: @Ming post your code on jsfiddle and paste the link here so that I can understand you. I dont know where do you want that shadow to be

Comment: deadlock, I added two images for description.
"left/right-shadow can be extended and appear from top to bottom"

Comment: @Ming you can set `min-height` css property on the wrapper. This will ensure that at anytime, the wrapper will not be shorter than the `min-height` you specify

Answer (score 0):

So idk if i understood good there are few ways to get "sticky footer"

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ <-one here

And in jQuery

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
var footer = $("footerselector");
var pos = footer.position();
var height = $(window).height();
height = height - pos.top;
height = height - footer.height();
    if (height > 0) {
      footer.css({'margin-top' : height+'px'});
  }
});
```