# CSS: Extended the height of page that equal the vertical resolution

Tags: html, css

I have written webpages like below structure and all the contents are inside `<div id="wrapper">`.

**Problem:** If the webpage has only few lines (shorter than the vertical resolution). How can I make sure the left/right-shadow can be extended so that it can appear from top to bottom?

It is appreciated if CSS be changed only. THX~

Change from this[image] to this[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#mainWrapper {
    width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
}
#wrapper {
    width:960px;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    padding:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    background:#fff;
}
#pageFooter {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    width:100%;
    background:#999;
}
</style>
</head>    
<body>
<div id="mainWrapper">
    <div id="wrapper">
        ContentContentContent
        <div id="pageFooter">
            FooterFooterFooter
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: duplicate of [CSS: Make sure footer at the bottom of the page and inside the shadow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22879606/css-make-sure-footer-at-the-bottom-of-the-page-and-inside-the-shadow) that you have already asked

Answer (score 0):

Use the `min-height` property.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

/* your wrapper */ {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aloisdg/Sq33r/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way to do it: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/IKDBG/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
#outer {
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.inner { display:table-row; }
#footer {
    background:#eee;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    height:1px;/* use a minimum height to keep footer wrapped to content */
}
#main {
    vertical-align:top;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px #000;
}
#main, #footer {
    display:table-cell;
    padding:5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer" >
        <div class="inner">
                <div id="main">
                        <p>Content content content</p>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
                <div id="footer">
                        <p>Footer <br>footer <br>footer</p>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Thanks to [Paul O'Brien](http://www.pmob.co.uk/temp/sticky-footer-auto-height.htm) for the template.)

Comment: You can easily move the shadow if needed. There's no shadow on your original footer image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add 100% height to the #wrapper. please don't quote me on this

Answer (score 0):

Here is another sticky footer option that keeps the footer 100%wide: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/aFrfs/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
html, body {height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}

* html #outer {
    height:100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: -240px auto 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
    width: 80%;
}

.content {padding-top: 240px; }

.footer {
    height: 240px; background: #999; color: #fff;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">Content content content</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer footer footer</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The limitation of this method is that the footer has a fixed height.